# Error in coding in Java with Mysql "Library Management System"

Tags: java, mysql

I've been working on this system and this error stops me to continue to code, there is no error in my code the output is the error. When i run the newStudent.java and type the data it show's that it's already existing, "Student ID Already Exist" you can see it in 46:20 in the Youtube video below. I hope someone help me, this will be a big help so ia can continue this system
[this is my output in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFmx.png)
[This is my source code in the button]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8Qj.png)`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLs-2N5mAow
I try to check if my connection is the problem but with the help of some AI Technologies, I see that the connection is active and try multiple times to recheck if i missed some of the code but I see its complete. I expect to resolve this issue so i can study more of it.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly. Other matters: you should be using `PreparedStatement` and closing database objects in try-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question. As far as I understand, "Student Id already exists" error occurs when new data is added. If I understood correctly, the error is that you entered the student Id data. Since the MySQL database is a relational database, a data is added to the database with a unique ID number. I think automatic setting of this Student ID data in database table settings will give the most accurate result. In this way, the ID number of the data will not conflict.

*Here you are trying to enroll a different student with the same value and this is wrong*

[Your code photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8Qj.png)

You are getting this error because you saved different data with the same ID in this photo. If you deleted the previous ID #1, the deleted data in relational databases actually remains inside. This is a legacy data protection method. The data continues from the next ID number. In other words, you must increase the ID values or the database should automatically increase it.